# Trying to Removing Duplicates in 1st column with out deleting rows. and the row values should be transposed to a original value. using java

Tags: java, excel

i am able to read the excel file in java & i am trying to remove the duplicates in column 1 by keeping the row values as it is and transforming the row values to a unique value in a same line as shown below.

My input excel sheet contains like this
[image]

My output file should look like this by deleting duplicates and tanspose the row values in a single line using a java program.
[image]

I used multimap to get the key values but how to get the key values seperated by a line with out mentioning the key in **myMultimap.get("Key")** which are stored in arraylist.

```
ArrayList l=new ArrayList();
        l.add(row.getCell(0).toString()); 
        ArrayList l1=new ArrayList();
        l1.add(row.getCell(1).toString());
        Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        myMultimap.put( ""+l, ""+l1);
        Collection<String> l2 = myMultimap.get(l);
        System.out.print(l2);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Huh. It's almost like you didn't try anything and just expect us to do your work for you. I usually charge for my services.

Comment: i tried but i am nt able to get what is the logic i should use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Guava MultiMap to achieve what you need.

```
Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

// Adding some key/value
myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Bannana");
myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Apple");
myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Pear");
myMultimap.put("Vegetables", "Carrot");

// Getting values
Collection<string> fruits = myMultimap.get("Fruits");
System.out.println(fruits); // [Bannana, Apple, Pear]
```

On the other hand, you can also use LambdaJ **groups** to generate exactly that too.

```
Group<Person> groupPeopleByAge = group(persons, by(on(Person.class).getAge()));
```

Comment: hi i am trying to get the values from a different keys which are stored in an arraylist.Can u suggest me how it can be possible to get all the keys by removing the duplicates line by line with their corresponding key value...
i used this Set<String> keys = myMultimap.keySet();
                for (String key : keys) {
             System.out.println(key);
    System.out.print("Values = " + myMultimap.get(key) + "n");
but all the keys with their corresponding values are getting

Answer (score 0):

You could imlpement a form of (or make use of) a hashmap with external chaining.

I like to implement my own, so here's a mock up.

```
List<Integer> keys;
List<String>[] map = new List<>[900];  //Use some number relative to the number of keys you have
for(row : rows){
    keys.add(row.col[0]);
    map[row.col[0]].add(row.col[1])
}
```

then write out each row

```
for(Integer i : keys){
    row.col[0] = i;
    row.col[1] = map[i]
}
```